# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: In android 6 and above

Tags: java, android

I am facing issue in android version 6 and above devices. My code is working fine with all the android devices which are less then android version 6.

[For **SSLSocketFactory** Code Please see the attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYj8W.jpg)

Here the logs :

> W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:563)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:444)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>         ... 23 more

Comment: It seems, you are using a certificate whose CA is no longer trusted in newer versions of Android.

Comment: **@Henry**   Thank you so much for your replay..   Could you please suggest me What can I do now..

Comment: Well, if that's the case then use a new certificate.